# Unable to upload file to git file size limit

Tags: laravel, git

I'm trying to push the code getting this error

```
remote: error: File storage/uploads.zip is 620 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
```

for the first time when i was pushing the code this uploads.zip file was there after that i deleted that folder now when i push the code getting this same error i have tried creating new branch but same issue is there

> gitignore file :

/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage
/vendor
.env
.env.backup
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Comment: It might be in a local commit. You might need to drop it

Answer (score 0):

You’ll probably have to break the zip folder into multiple zipped folders or upload that zip to a different cloud storage solution and then reference it in your code via a URL.

Comment: i don't want to upload that folder in gitignore i have added folder path and also deleted from my project